# Get picture from xml ( VB.net )

Tags: xml, vb.net, image, binary

I have more xml file what store image in binary format.
Is there any method to add this data to a picurebox?

```
  <Thumbnail image-type="bmp" image-encoding="base64Binary">
    <![CDATA[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]]>
  </Thumbnail>
```

Best Reagds,

Tibi

I need a start kick, because i don't work with binary pictures.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is base64 so first you have to use convert to get a byte array : Convert.FromBase64String.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq


Module Program
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)
        Dim Xml As String = doc.Root.Value
        Dim image As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Xml)
    End Sub
End Module
```